# A function on ideals that converts intersection to sum

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

For a commutative ring with identity, we know that the
annihilator (as a function on ideals) of the sum of some ideals equals to the intersection
of their annihilators, I am looking for a function on ideals, say
$F$, of a commutative ring that $F$ of the  intersection of some
ideals equals to  the sum $F$ of them.

Answer (score 0):

The best result I know in this direction (still using the annihilator map) is in the work of [G. F. Birkenmeier, M. Ghirati & A. Taherifar](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2014.882931).

For instance, this determined that among semiprime rings, the quasi-Baer ones had the property you’re describing.

I haven’t really seen any other order reversing maps with the property you’re speaking of.